# widgets.FileUpload - Read the uploaded CSV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am using `widgets.FileUpload` to upload a CSV to jupyter and read it. I am using below yo upload.

```
input_file = widgets.FileUpload(
    accept='.csv',  # Accepted file extension e.g. '.txt', '.pdf', 'image/*', 'image/*,.pdf'
    multiple=False  # True to accept multiple files upload else False
)

input_file
```

I have uplaoded the file and when i print `print(input_file.value)` I can see the data.

But when i read through `data = pd.read_csv(input_file.value, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")` I see below error

`ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>`

Any pointers please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input_file.value` is normally a tuple of dicts, hence you need to access the actual file data. This is probably under `input_file.value[0]['content']` if you have only uploaded one file. Try this:

```py
import codecs
uploaded_file = list(input_file.value.values())[0]
csv_text = codecs.decode(uploaded_file.content)
data = pd.read_csv(csv_text)
```

See here for more information: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#File-Upload

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and I am seeing an `Key Error: 0`

Comment: please share the full error, and also what you see when you run `input_file.value`

Comment: @24 - `KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-1dbe6fbd8f83> in <module>
      1 import codecs
----> 2 uploaded_file = input_file.value[0]
      3 csv_text = codecs.decode(uploaded_file.content)
      4 data = pd.read_csv(csv_text)

KeyError: 0`

Comment: `input_file.value` its huge CSV first few line looks like `{'Test.csv': {'metadata': {'name': 'Test.csv', 'type': 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'size': 198933, 'lastModified': 1619167436578}, 'content': b'ColumnName\r\nRow1 data\r\nTo close Open CRQ\'s`

Comment: That structure doesn't really match what is expected from the docs. Can you check your ipywidgets version (`widgets.__version__`)

Comment: @ ac24 - The version is '7.6.3'

Comment: Hmm I think the docs are incorrect then.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @ac24 my labs are showtdown now, will test and update on monday. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried the recommended, but i am seeing below error - `----> 3 csv_text = codecs.decode(uploaded_file.content)
      4 data = pd.read_csv(csv_text)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'content'` Any pointers.